# QGIS - Label masks breaks layer on PDF export

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, pdf, masking

I have a contour lines layer with index labels, which uses masks, it works correctly on the editor and composer as seen below

[image: on composer]

When exported the layer goes past map boundaries and it's style breaks.

[image: pdf export with masks]

Without using masks the export works as expected.

[image: pdf export without masks]

Is this a bug? Or are masks not supported on pdf export? In any case, is there anyway to circumvent this?

Comment: I don't seem to have that problem, but in my experience I haven't been able to export pdfs with masks unless printed as a raster, so I don't think there is very good support generally

Comment: @she_weeds I found out today by accident that label masking now works even with vector PDFs (QGIS 3.32.3). I have no idea when this feature was quietly added.

Comment: Ok, it's always adviseable to read the change logs. This feature was added in QGIS 3.26: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-selective-masking-vectorization